# How do I get the Perl's DateTime::Format::DateManip version number from the command line?

Tags: perl, command-line, module-versions

I'm using this from the command line:

```
perl -MDateTime::Format::DateManip -le 'print $Some::Module::VERSION'
```

but only return a blank line, any thoughts?

Comment: The question is better titled "How do I get a Perl module's version number from the command line?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is pseudo-code, `Some` isn't set so it is just printing out `undef` with the `-l` flag, like `perl -le'print undef`;

For evidence turn on warnings with `-w`

```
$ perl -MDateTime::Format::DateManip -wle 'print $Some::Module::VERSION'
Use of uninitialized value $Some::Module::VERSION in print at -e line 1.
```

Substitute `Some::Module` with the module you want the version of.

Also, just for fun ;)

### Perl Shorthands for testing version numbers

These are quick ways to get version numbers by utilizing the `use <module> <version>` syntax and perl's vocal rejection of versions that aren't new enough.

These are all equivalent of creating a perl script with `use DateTime 9999;`

```
$ perl -MDateTime\ 9999
DateTime version 9999 required--this is only version 0.51.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

However, this fashion isn't cross-platform, because you're simply telling bash to escape a space. This doesn't work in windows `cmd`, for that you'll have to

```
$ perl -M"DateTime 9999"
DateTime version 9999 required--this is only version 0.51.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

Here, you just put it in quotes - that tells cmd to send it all as an argument to perl and it gets the same job done.

Comment: Thanks, I see now: perl -MDateTime::Format::DateManip -wle 'print $DateTime::Format::DateManip::VERSION'

Comment: I use this bash alias to fetch version numbers: `perlversion() { perl -M$1 -wle'print $ARGV[0]->VERSION' $1 }`

Answer (score 2):

If you find yourself doing this frequently, you can download and install [pmvers](http://search.cpan.org/~mlfisher/pmtools-1.10/pmvers) from CPAN. The script will save you from typing a potentially lengthy module name twice:

```
pmvers DateTime::Format::DateManip
```